# What is the default location of inetmgr.exe of IIS in Windows 7, as none of my Windows searches are working; Any Alternative to access it?

Tags: iis, windows-7, windows-services

Hi I want to acces, open "inetmgr.exe" on my Windows 7 machine.  But none of the searches are working. ( Start Menu --> Search Program and Files  NOR  Search in My Computer).
    I somehow want to access inetmgr.exe of IIS(InternetInformation Services).

> So can anyone kindly let me know the
>   default location of inetmgr.exe or any
>   DOS command to access it.  I even
>   tried typing "inetmgr.exe" in command
>   prompt. But not working. So PLz
>   somehow I need to access inetmgr.exe.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should be in superuser.com, you will get much better response there. Also do you mean IIS or ISS?

Comment: Hi I am really sorry. I meant IIS (Internet Information Services).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It should be available in following location:
`C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe`

But when you goto start menu and type inetmgr.exe it should be visible in the list. If not then something wrong with your installation or that file has been deleted.

Comment: I found the file "InetMgr.exe" in the location specified by you. Thanks. But in my system none of the searches are working. Dont know why. The search is getting confined to notepad files.

Comment: @engineerMaster: I'm glad that it helped you. Post question on SuperUser.com with details about your search problem, I'm sure you will get the answer.

Comment: Ok sure I will do it. Thank you. :)

Comment: Note that launching this fails from a 32 bit application because of file system redirection silently putting you in syswow64. Here's an [article from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) and a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487653/how-can-disable-redirection-on-win64)

Answer (score 12):

At first check IIS is installed or not.

***For XP***

- Open Control Panel
- Add-Remove Windows Components.

***For Windows 7 / Windows Server 2012***

- Open Control Panel
- Programs and Features
- Turn Windows features on or off.

Comment: Not an answer to the question?

Comment: Actually it is an answer for cases before you should check. At least it gets 10 up votes which show it helps.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Go into Control Panel -> Programs-> Turn Windows features on or off.

Click on features for Internet Information Services. Specifically, Web Management Tools and Wold Wide Web Services.

For Web Management Tools
   ->IIS 6 Management Compatibility
      ->IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility. (or any other features you think you may need)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows Server 2016 with it not wanting to search. IIS Manager (with our normal websites) was showing in the Start menu but IIS 6 Manager was not (where the SMTP Virtual Server settings are located).

Luckily you can launch it from within Server Manager:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I installed IIS and still couldn't find InetMgr.exe until I went back to

> **Turn Windows features on or off**

and then checked

> - Internet Information Services
>
> > - Web Management Tools
> >
> > > - **IIS Management Console**