# How to fix winmgmt error code 0x8007007E?

Tags: c#

I'm making C# wrapper class for executing winmgmt and command keeps failing.

I tried setting the `StartInfo.Verb` parameter to `"runas"` but it did not help. C# application is already elevated.

Running command `winmgmt /verifyrepository` in elevated command prompt works just fine.

```
public static void VerifyRepository()
{
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"winmgmt";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/verifyrepository";
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
WMIVerifyResultReceived?.Invoke(null, new WMIVerifyResultReceivedEventArgs(output));
}
```

When ran in cmd output is

`WMI repository is consistent`

but when ran using `VerifyRepository()` method i keep getting this output on same machine:

`WMI repository verification failed
Error code:  0x8007007E`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused because app was run in WOW64 (32bit on 64bit) so the path of winmgmt was in systemwow64 folder and service was running in 64bit mode. 
Fixed it by unchecking prefer 32bit in build options. 
Another way to fix this without disabling prefer 32bit is to use wow64apiset call [Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-wow64disablewow64fsredirection) at the start of verifyrepository method and then at the end to call [Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-wow64revertwow64fsredirection) function like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487653/how-can-disable-redirection-on-win64):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref IntPtr ptr);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(IntPtr ptr);

public static void VerifyRepository()
{
var wow64Value = IntPtr.Zero;
Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref wow64Value);
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"winmgmt";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/verifyrepository";
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(wow64Value);
WMIVerifyResultReceived?.Invoke(null, new WMIVerifyResultReceivedEventArgs(output));
}
```

Note that if you have prefer 32bit unchecked there is no need to use wow64apiset calls.