# How to run Powershell command in C# in all platforms

Tags: c#, powershell, x86, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I want to run power shell command on a simple console app.

I'm running on `x64` platform.

As I'm running with `AnyCpu` option it's not working.

I'm getting error `pnputil : The term 'pnputil' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,`

If i'm running with `x64` option it's working.

***How can I run the application so it'll work on platforms(e.g on x32 , x64)***

***Without specifying manually?***

Thank You.

**Edit**:

I can solve it with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487653/how-can-disable-redirection-on-win64). but don't want as it's not safe.

Comment: I found that when you set the "Any CPU" platform, also try unchecking the "Prefer 32-bit" option in Project Properties window.
Is helping on x64 but not sure about x32

Comment: You're trying to circumvent filesystem redirection, so why not disable file system redirection? What exactly do you mean by "as it's not safe"?

Comment: Microsoft documentation: Note  This value is for system use only. To avoid unpredictable behavior, do not modify this value in any way. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-wow64disablewow64fsredirection

Comment: That's not about the function itself, it's telling you not to modify the _output value from the function call_ - so just _don't do that_ and you're good :)

Comment: Terminology: not all C# implementations are on systems with Powershell.  e.g. C# on a Linux system won't have it.  Sounds like you mean "CPU architecture" for a Windows application.  That's not what I'd assume from the word "all platforms".  But maybe that's standard terminology in the C# world, IDK.